# How to use Mocha require option in Karma

Tags: mocha.js, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I've been trying to use the mocha require option:

```
mocha mytest.js --require myglobals.js
```

But I don't know how to do it from karma. The idea is to run `karma start` and it will automatically require `myglobals.js`.

Is that possible to do it from within `karma.conf.js` or somehow else?

Maybe I'm not using karma/mocha in the right way.

My idea is:

- I want to have unit/integration tests for both the client (react) and the server (node/express)
- I want to just run `karma start` and both client and server tests are tested
- I found very useful to have the following file pre-required, in order to avoid requiring some things in all tests:

`myglobals.js`:

```
const chai = require('chai');

// Load Chai assertions
global.expect = chai.expect;
global.assert = chai.assert;
chai.should();

// Load Sinon
global.sinon = require('sinon');

// Initialize Chai plugins
chai.use(require('sinon-chai'));
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
chai.use(require('chai-things'));
```

For the server side I've made it work using the command:

```
mocha mytest.js --require myglobals.js
```

But still, I wanted to keep it running under the `npm run test` *(which calls `karma start`)* instead of creating another `npm run test:server` command.

Furthermore, I wanted to do the same on the client. I'm using webpack there as a preprocessor.

Any ideas if it is possible to accomplish that? Or maybe I'm in the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Mocha in the browser does not support an equivalent of the `--require` option, but you do not need it. You can just load whatever you need ahead of your tests listing the files you want to load in `files` in front of your test files. Or if you use a loader like RequireJS, write a `test-main.js` that loads the modules you would load with `--require` first, and then load your test files.

#### Long Answer

If you look at Mocha's code you'll see that the only place `--require` is used is in the [`bin/_mocha`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/b76989ceb8ca38b4ad9a2df4892581d96e8c4ba8/bin/_mocha#L171) file. This option is not passed further into the Mocha code but is immediately used to [load the requested modules](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/b76989ceb8ca38b4ad9a2df4892581d96e8c4ba8/bin/_mocha#L310):

```
requires.forEach(function(mod) {
  require(mod);
});
```

When you run Mocha in the browser, none of this code is run, and if you look in the rest of the Mocha code you won't find a similar facility anywhere else. Why?

Because it would serve no purpose. The `--require` option is very useful at the command line. Without it, the only way to load modules before Mocha loads the test files would be to either write custom code to start Mocha or put the necessary `require` calls at the start of every single test file.

In the browser, if you do not use a module loader, you can just load the code you'd load using `--require` by putting the `script` elements that load them in front of the `script` elements that load your tests. In Karma, this means putting these files earlier in the list of `files` you have in your `karma.conf.js`. Or if you use RequireJS, for instance, you write `test-main.js` so that the loading is done in two phases: one that loads the modules you'd load through `--require` on the command-line, and a second that loads your test files. It could be something like:

```
const allTestFiles = [];
const TEST_REGEXP = /test\/test.*\.js$/i;

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach((file) => {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    const normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, "");
    allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
  }
});

require.config({
  baseUrl: "/base",
  paths: {
     ...
  },
});

// This guarantees that "a", "b", "c" loads before any other module
require(["a", "b", "c", ...], () => {
  require(allTestFiles, window.__karma__.start);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Louis, awesome answer. Thank you very much for your quick and detailed answer. Maybe I'm not using karma/mocha in the right way. Would you be so kind to take a look at the "Updated 1" part of my question? (since I can't post so much things here in the comment)

Comment: Ok, updated. Maybe now is more clear what I want to accomplish (I should have written that since the beginning :S ). Thanks beforehand

Comment: What I describe in my answer should work for your case, with the following caveats: 1) `global` does not exist in browsers; use `window` instead. 2) browsers do not have `require`; use the Karma plugins `karma-mocha`, `karma-chai`, etc. to load `mocha`, `chai`, etc. before your tests. Please try it, and if it does not work then post a new question with your `karma.conf.js` and the file you are trying to load before your tests. You should also revert your edit here. The community does not approve of substantial edits to questions that have already been answered.

Comment: I will try your suggestions as soon as I can. Thanks again and sorry about the edit, is something I've seen being done, but I didn't know it was discouraged in the community.

Comment: @AlexJ I'm not surprised you've seen it happen. Unfortunately, not everybody knows that it is something the community frowns upon. And there *are* some cases where editing the question substantially is the correct way to move forward. For instance, if the original question was utterly incomprehensible but people started answering anyway, then editing the question is the way to go.